# How to pack scale space pyramid of images on the plane in most compact way?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, computer-vision

I'm looking for algorithm to pack scale space pyramid of images on the plane in most compact way?

Here is an example what I mean:

Pyramid of images:

[image]

wanted result:

[image]

Comment: As usual, this type of question is very underspecified.  The top image suggests that each image is half the width and height of the previous: in that case, to minimise the area of a bounding rectangle containing all images (you don't say whether you want to minimise this area, or width or height or perhaps something else) you can put the 2nd-largest image alongside the largest, and fit *all* smaller images directly below it -- this will fit any number of images, and is optimal.  But your second image suggests something different is needed...

Comment: @j_random_hacker scale step may be different from 0.5, I need general solution. I need to minimize the area of resulting image.

Comment: Does the compact combined images have to all be visible in the final result? Can you use a custom format to read the images?

Comment: @Seph result must be in same representation as input image.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210979/Fast-optimizing-rectangle-packing-algorithm-for-bu